# What is the “dt” in the complementary filter equation and how do I find out the “dt”?

Tags: filter, accelerometer, gyroscope

I am trying to implement a complementary filter in my system but I do not quite understand what "dt" means and how should I find out the "dt" in the complementary filter equation.

I found the complementary filter equation [here.](https://www.pieter-jan.com/node/11)

This is the equation:

$$angle = 0.98 * (angle + gyrData * dt) + 0.02 * (accData)$$

This is the code I am using now:

```
while n!= 10:

data = bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x68, 0x3B, 6)

xAccl = data[0] * 256 + data[1]
if xAccl > 32767 :
        xAccl -= 65536

yAccl = data[2] * 256 + data[3]
if yAccl > 32767 :
        yAccl -= 65536

zAccl = data[4] * 256 + data[5]
if zAccl > 32767 :
        zAccl -= 65536

data = bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x68, 0x43, 6)

xGyro = data[0] * 256 + data[1]
if xGyro > 32767 :
        xGyro -= 65536

yGyro = data[2] * 256 + data[3]
if yGyro > 32767 :
        yGyro -= 65536

zGyro = data[4] * 256 + data[5]
if zGyro > 32767 :
        zGyro -= 65536

totZdata += zAccl
totXdata += xAccl
totYdata += yAccl
totGyroXdata += xGyro
totGyroYdata += yGyro
totGyroZdata += zGyro
zAcclG = (zAccl - AcclzOff) / Accl_scale
xAcclG = (xAccl - AcclxOff) / Accl_scale
yAcclG = (yAccl - AcclyOff) / Accl_scale
xGyroDPS = (xGyro - GyroxOff) / Gyro_scale
yGyroDPS = (yGyro - GyroyOff) / Gyro_scale
zGyroDPS = (zGyro - GyrozOff) / Gyro_scale    


print ("Acceleration in X-Axis : %.2f G" %xAcclG)
print ("Acceleration in Y-Axis : %.2f G" %yAcclG)
print ("Acceleration in Z-Axis : %.2f G" %zAcclG)
print (" X rotation : %f" % (get_x_rotation(xAcclG, yAcclG, zAcclG)))
print (" Y rotation : %f" % (get_y_rotation(xAcclG, yAcclG, zAcclG)))
print ("X-Axis of Rotation : %.2f" %xGyroDPS)
print ("Y-Axis of Rotation : %.2f" %yGyroDPS)
print ("Z-Axis of Rotation : %.2f" %zGyroDPS)
n += 1
```

How can I determine the "dt" from the cmplementary filter equation?

Comment: #define dt 0.01       // 10 ms sample rate!

Comment: I do not understand why the author get to set the dt as 0.1 .

Comment: where? .........

Comment: dt is just the time between two calls of the routine you posted. There should be a TIMER  or alike in your code doing so at a rate of your choice.

Comment: Wait, now i know what dt means. But this i do not quite understand. "There should be a TIMER or alike in your code doing so at a rate of your choice"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\$dt\$ in that expression is the time step.  So if you're sampling at 100Hz, \$dt = 10\mathrm{ms}\$, if you're sampling at 500Hz, \$dt = 2\mathrm{ms}\$, etc.

Comment: But, how can i know about the sampling rate?

Comment: @ckkkk Read the datasheet?

Comment: I meant how do i know if the sensor actually really did output that much of data?

Comment: That's entirely a separate problem, and way too complicated to answer as a comment in something unrelated.  If you're concerned, ask it separately.  The bottom line, though, is that you check to make sure.

Comment: Yea, by default its 100Hz so i am good, so i should just follow the author and set the dt to 0.01?

Answer (score 0):

Its the period (in ms) of your filter routine.

Comment: Means how many sensor data i can get?

Comment: No, it means a time difference between two last new values. In your example, the time between two readings from sensor.

Comment: Oh its like how many ms required for 1 data reading